# How can I successfully redirect/pass a json object via click event to another page in ejs, express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, express, ejs

I am trying to redirect a json object in ejs via a click event to another page. How is this done successfully in ejs, express & nodejs? I have google searched for almost a week now and can't seem to find anything that works for me. Apparently, I am a newbie to all these.

Right now, when I click the button I see the object in the alert inside the function in ejs. If I access any member of the object in console log within the function in ejs, I get undefined.

Through the route on the server side is the same result. I see the object in console log but cannot access it. I pass the entire object to the new page, it displays the whole content but cannot access specific members like the id, email etc.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!-- this is the button -->
<td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    name="theButton"
                    class="edit-selected btn btn-ship btn-sm"
                    onclick="editOrder()"
                  >
                    Ed
                  </button>
                </td>
                
 <!-- this is the function in ejs -->
 <% for(let i=0; i < user.pickups.length; i++){%>
<script>
  function editOrder() {
    var pickup = '<%- JSON.stringify(pickup[i]) %>'
    alert(pickup)
    if (pickup) {
      window.location = '/users/dashboard/orders?' + pickup
    }
  }
</script>
<%}%>
```

```js
<!-- Output in console log via server side when access using query string or url -->
[Object: null prototype] {
  '{"orderItems":{"items":["Water packs"],"qty":["4"]},"_id":"61624e90dcc1ca1e84ff1c04","fname":"Micky","lname":"Mouse","company":"","contacts":{"phone":5557770000,"email":"kam@kem.com","address":{"street":"10 Merrybrook Drive","apt":"","city":"Herndon","state":"VA","zip":"21171","country":"United States","_id":"61624e90dcc1ca1e84ff1c06"},"_id":"61624e90dcc1ca1e84ff1c05"},"pickupDate":"2021-10-10","pickupTime":"1930","user":"615bbccbfc4e310ca52f3a20","createdAt":"2021-10-10T02:23:12.131Z","updatedAt":"2021-10-10T02:23:12.131Z","__v":0}': ''
}
```

```js
<!-- this is what data looks like from the database -->
{
    orderItems: { items: [Array], qty: [Array] },
    _id: new ObjectId("61624e90dcc1ca1e84ff1c04"),
    fname: 'Micky',
    lname: 'Mouse',
    company: '',
    contacts: {
      phone: 5557770000,
      email: 'kam@kem.com',
      address: [Object],
      _id: new ObjectId("61624e90dcc1ca1e84ff1c05")
    },
    pickupDate: '2021-10-10',
    pickupTime: '1930',
    user: new ObjectId("615bbccbfc4e310ca52f3a20"),
    createdAt: 2021-10-10T02:23:12.131Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-10-10T02:23:12.131Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

```js
<!-- Express route -->
router.get('/users/dashboard/orders', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orders = url.parse(req.url, true).query
    console.log(orders)

    res.render('orders')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

Comment: You should post the data to the server, save it in db or session, and render the new page with the saved data. Another option is to save it in session storage on the browser.

Comment: Please can you demonstrate here for me? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at these, for starters: https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-express-js-mysql-rest-api-example/ https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/